# Hibernate - automatic @ManyToMany update

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, many-to-many, cascade

I have `Article` entity, which has related `Tag`s:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "articles")
public class Article implements Serializable{
   //other things

   @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
   private List<Tag> tags;
}
```

And `Tag` entity, which has related `Article`s:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
public class Tag implements Serializable{
    //other things

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Article> articles;
}
```

Is there any chance to configure `Annotations` in way, that if I save `Article` with specified `Tag`:

```
//simplified code
Tag tag = new Tag();
tags.add(tag)

article.setTags(tags);

articleService.save(article);
```

`Article`s related with `Tag` **will be updated automatically**, without axplicite call `add` method (`tag.getArticles().add(article)`)? Or I have to do it manually?

This is part of unit test which shows what I try to achieve:

```
service.save(new TagDTO(null, tagValue, emptyArticles));
TagDTO tag = service.getAll().get(0);
List<TagDTO> tags = new ArrayList<>();
tags.add(tag);
articleService.save(new ArticleDTO(null, tags, articleContent));

List<ArticleDTO> articles = articleService.getAll();
assertEquals(1, articles.size());
final ArticleDTO articleWithTags = articles.get(0);
assertEquals(1, articleWithTags.getTags().size());
tags = service.getAll();
assertEquals(1, tags.size());
final TagDTO tagWithArticle = tags.get(0);
final List<ArticleDTO> articlesWithTag = tagWithArticle.getArticles();
assertEquals(1, articlesWithTag.size()); //it fails
```

Which is failing now, because `Tag` wasn't updated with related `Article`.

Thank you in advance for answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `mappedBy` attribute on your many-to-many relationship. If you don't use it, then hibernate thinks that you have two differente unidirectional relationships.
I mean your code represents this:

- `Article * ------------------[tags]-> * Tag`
- `Tag * ------------------[articles]-> * Article`

instead of this:

- `Article * <-[articles]------[tags]-> * Tag`

Here is one way to make just one many-to-many bidirectional relationship between `Article` and `Tag`. Note the `mappedBy` attribute on Tag->articles collection.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "articles")
public class Article implements Serializable{
   //other things

   @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
   private List<Tag> tags;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
public class Tag implements Serializable{
    //other things

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="tags" ,cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Article> articles;
}
```

Edit: Take a look at this [Hibernate Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-bidirectional) to see how to code differente bidirectional associations scenarios.